# Sending freeform submissions to multiple recipients

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

We need to send to three email addresses when a particular select option is selected. I've tried setting the value of that field (called recipient_email) to foo@bar.com,baz@bar.com and setting recipients=yes and recipient_limit=3 on the form, but the form just comes through to the default admin notification email.

Any suggestions? This in on EE 2.6.1 and Freeform 4.0.12.

Here's a cut down version of the template code:

```
{exp:freeform:form 
collection="General Contact Form"
return="{embed:return}/category/submitted" 
form:id="form-general-contact" 
form:class="validate no-print" 
required="first_name|surname|email|recipient_email|user_message"
recipients="yes" 
recipient_limit="3"
}

<fieldset>

    <div class="fr">
        <label for="sel-general-type">Enquiry Type <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <div class="wrapper-select">
            <select id="sel-general-type" name="recipient_email">
                <option value="foo@bar.com,baz@bar.com">Foo</option>
                <option value="bar@foo.com">Bar</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 6):

The `recipient_email` field accepts **encoded recipient email values** ([see an example here](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipient_email)), using the `{freeform:recipient_value}` variable in the field's `name=""` attribute along with a set list of recipients using `recipient1=""`, `recipient2=""`, etc parameters.

If you want your field's value="" to be an regular, *non-encoded* email address (as you have it above), use `recipient_email_user` field ([documentation](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#recipient_email_user)).

To send to multiple recipients, use `name="recipient_email[]"` or `name="recipient_email_user[]"` for your field. Please note the brackets `[]`.

**You cannot have more than one email address as a field's value=""**.

**In your case, however,** you are using a select field, which cannot accept multiple values. Either change the field to checkboxes or a multi-select field, eg.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="recipient_email_user[]" value="email1@example.com" /> Recipient 1<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="recipient_email_user[]" value="email2@example.com" /> Recipient 2<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="recipient_email_user[]" value="email3@example.com" /> Recipient 3<br />
```

...or use javascript/jQuery to populate hidden `recipient_email_user[]` fields when a select field option is selected.