# Sending to multiple recipients dynamically via freeform in EE1.6.8

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace, email, ee1

I have been over the docs and still fall short on this one.

I have a form where customers can dynamically add referrals to notify. I just can't get the email to send.

Here is my freeform code:

```
        {exp:freeform:form 
            secure_return="yes" 
            collection="Loyalty Rewards Referrals" 
            required="loyalty_customer_number|loyalty_customer_name|loyalty_referral_name|loyalty_referral_email" 
            form_name="referral_form" 
            form_id="referral_form" 
            template="loyalty_rewards_referral_notice" 
            return="/loyalty/thanks" 
            recipients="yes" 
            recipient_template="loyalty_rewards_referral_notice_email" 
            require_ip="yes" 
        }
```

I have tried a few different things, but here is the last bit:

```
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_customer_number" id="loyalty_customer_number"  />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_customer_name" id="loyalty_customer_name" />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_referral_name" id="loyalty_referral_name" />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_referral_email" id="loyalty_referral_email" />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="recipient_email_user[]" id="recipient_email_user[]" />
```

The form itself is hidden and I do some backend validating, during which I add the following prior to submitting:

```
    //  Create the needed fields in the form
    for (i = 0; i < combinedReferrals.length; ++i) {
        $('<input class="form_field" type="text" name="recipient' + i + '" value="' + combinedReferrals[i] + '" />').insertAfter('.form_field:last');
    }
```

Which adds the fields for the dynamic referrals in the format of:

```
<input class="form_field" type="text" name="recipient1" value="Brian|myEmail@email.com" />
<input class="form_field" type="text" name="recipient2" value="Joe|hisEmail@email.com" />
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

*** EDIT ***

Entire freeform code here:

```
        {exp:freeform:form 
            secure_return="yes" 
            collection="Loyalty Rewards Referrals" 
            required="loyalty_customer_number|loyalty_customer_name" 
            form_name="referral_form" 
            form_id="referral_form" 
            require_ip="yes" 
            template="loyalty_rewards_referral_notice" 
            notify="me@myemail.com" 
            return="/loyalty/thanks" 
            recipient_user_input="yes" 
            recipient_user_limit="1" 
            recipient_user_template="loyalty_rewards_referral_notice_email" 
        }
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_customer_number" id="loyalty_customer_number"  />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_customer_name" id="loyalty_customer_name" />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_referral_name" id="loyalty_referral_name" />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_referral_email" id="loyalty_referral_email" />
        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Then prior to submit, I loop through an array of entries and populate the following:

```
    //  Create the needed fields in the form
    for (i = 0; i < combinedReferrals.length; ++i) {
        //$('<input class="form_field" type="text" name="recipient' + i + '" value="' + combinedReferrals[i] + '" />').insertAfter('.form_field:last');
        $('<input class="form_field" type="checkbox" name="recipient_email_user[]" value="' + combinedReferrals[i] + '" checked />').insertAfter('.form_field:last');
    }
```

Where 'combinedReferrals[i]' is 'Brian|me@myemail.com'.

*** EDIT ***

I have the emails sending now using the following code:

```
        {exp:freeform:form 
            form_name="referral_form" 
            form_id="referral_form" 
            notify="me@myemail.com" 
            require_ip="yes" 
            secure_return="yes" 
            collection="Loyalty Rewards Referrals" 
            required="loyalty_customer_number|loyalty_customer_name" 
            return="/loyalty/thanks" 
            recipients="yes" 
            recipient_limit="10" 
            recipient_template="loyalty_rewards_referral_notice_email" 
        }
            <!-- Customer Fields -->
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_customer_number" id="loyalty_customer_number"  />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_customer_name" id="loyalty_customer_name" />

            <!-- Referral Fields -->
            <!-- Limit 10 -->

            <!-- FreeForm Data -->
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_referral_name" id="loyalty_referral_name" />
            <input class="form_field" type="text" name="loyalty_referral_email" id="loyalty_referral_email" />
        {/exp:freeform:form}
```

Then the following is writing the values prior to submission:

```
    //  Create the needed fields in the form
    var splitValue;
    for (i = 0; i < combinedReferrals.length; ++i) {
        //  Split the result
        splitValue = combinedReferrals[i].toString().split("|");

        //  Populate the form
        $('<input class="form_field" type="text" name="recipient_name[]" value="' + splitValue[0] + '" />').insertAfter('.form_field:last');
        $('<input class="form_field" type="text" name="recipient_email[]" value="' + splitValue[1] + '" />').insertAfter('.form_field:last');
    }
```

Each email is sent to each recipient as it should. However, they want to use the recipient NAME field to personalize the email sent. If I try to use `{recipient_name}` I get nothing.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: What does "I just can't get the email to send." mean exactly?  Are the entries added to the database?  Do you get an error?  What?  Also what version of FreeForm are you using?

Comment: I've been looking through this example: http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12734/sending-freeform-submissions-to-multiple-recipients           

When I say I can't get an email to send, I mean a recipient email. The notification email triggers, but not the recipient emails. This happens even if I "hard code" the fields with values. I am updating my entry above to show current code.

Comment: And what version of FreeForm are you using please?

Comment: This might be a javascript issue now.  When you inspect the html (with Chrome or Safari inspector) do you see the expected value for recipient_name in your dynamic input field?

Comment: FreeForm 3x...     
I see the fields as they should be. In order to process them in this fashion, they are in arrays. From the docs, I gathered that the array is how to accumulate the multiple email addresses. However, if I do this with the names, it doesn't break them out. Instead, it displays them all as a comma separated list.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure this approach is going to work.

FreeForm expects you to define `recipient1` and `recipient2` as a parameter of the `exp:freeform:form` tag, they are then encoded on the server side and the html source only shows a hashed value for the recipient, not the value you are inserting dynamically.

If the method you described here were to be permitted then it would be simple to hijack the form to send email to anyone and it would be rife for abuse by spammers.

Solspace's solution to "tell a friend" and potentially what you want to do is the `recipient_user_input="yes"`value in the `exp:freeform:form` tag.  You have this value as an `input` but not in the `exp:freeform:form` tag.  I've read the docs a couple of times and I don't think that you can use recipient1...2...3... with this approach, but I could be wrong.

Take a look at the [tell-a-friend](http://www.solspace.com/docs/freeform/form/#tellafriend_form) example in the docs.

I think you'll need to specify `recipient_user_template` instead of `recipient_template`.  You'll probably want/need to set `recipient_user_limit` as well.